# Mod Rewrite help apache - turning pretty URLs into PHP acceptable links

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

Right now I'm using this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/?$ profile.php?userName=$1 [L]
```

This works for normal cases without spaces or underscores, etc...  just the basics.

I need it to be pretty open to characters though - such as  `John_doe john-doe john doe`.

I've tried a lot of other Regex's, but I can't seem to get one that works for everything.  Much appreciate any help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.` character will match any single character:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ profile.php?userName=$1 [L]
```

Note the use of this regex is discouraged because of character encoding purposes (and SEO as well, but I don't know if it's relevant to you). It's always better to have addresses containing only lower case alphanumeric characters and dashes (`-`).

For more info about mod_rewrite regex, see [this link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html#regex).

Comment: hm, I suppose I can stick to dashes then.  Why is that better for SEO?

Comment: TBH, SEO is not a precise science so there are debates about what I said in my answer. The only sure thing about Google is that "foo-bar" will match a search for "foo bar", while "foo_bar" won't.